# Removing a character into a string

Tags: string, vb.net

I have a series of strings into a Listbox and in this string there could be a slash ("/") that I need to remove. What I've done is to provide the following code:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox9.Items.Count - 1
  If ListBox9.Items(i).ToString().Contains("/") = True Then
    ListBox9.Items(i).ToString().Replace(Chr(47), Chr(32))
  End If
Next
```

I though that the sintax was correct but the code actually isn't working: if the string contains /, it's not remove by the replace command. I'm not using the remove command, since the position of the slash may be different from a case to another.
Hoping to have been clear, I thank in advance all are gonna support me.
Best regards

Comment: Replace the item itself: `ListBox9.Items(i) = ListBox9.Items(i).ToString().Replace(Chr(47), Chr(32))`. Or better, assign it to a variable, modify the variable, then replace the list item with the variable.

Comment: Solved as you said, thanks a lot!